# Func Delegate Equivalent for System.Linq.Join Parameters

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, delegates, func

I have the following code:

```
List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
List<PersonType> PeopleTypes = new List<PersonType>();

var JoinedLists = People.Join(PeopleTypes, PeopleKey => PeopleKey.PersonType, PeopleTypesKey => PeopleTypesKey.TypeID, (Person, PersonType) => new { Name = Person.Name, TypeID = PersonType.TypeID });
```

Now I want to create a method for this code for it to be reusable. So far I have come up to this:

```
 List<T> ListJoin<T, S>(List<T> FirstTable, List<T> SecondTable, Func<T, S> OuterKeySelectorExpr, Func<T, S> InnerKeySelectorExpr, _______ ResultSelectorExpr)
 {
     FirstTable.Join(SecondTable, OuterKeySelectorExpr, InnerKeySelectorExpr, ResultSelectorExpr);
 }
```

Am I doing it correctly? What is the equivalent Func<> delegate for the result selector of the join extension?

Comment: How is `ListJoin` going to be different from a normal `join`?

Comment: Well I'm planning on adding more code below the `join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with anonymous types. What you really ask for is:

```
Func<T, S, WeirdAnonymousTypeHere>
```

but the anonymous types are no-name types, so the type of `new { Name = Person.Name, TypeID = PersonType.TypeID }` has no name and cannot be specified.

However, sometimes the type can be inferred from usage, so you might give your method a third generic parameter:

```
ListJoin<T, S, R>
```

where `R` (and hence also `T` and `S`) are supposed to be inferred from usage when you call the method, and then the last parameter of your method would be

```
Func<T, S, R> resultSelector
```

of course.

So the full signature would be:

```
static List<R> ListJoin<T, S, R>(List<T> firstTable, List<T> secondTable,
    Func<T, S> outerKeySelector, Func<T, S> innerKeySelector,
    Func<T, S, R> resultSelector)
```

or maybe something similar.

Compare with the signature of Linq-To-Object's `Join` method ([see documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx)):

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
    Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector, Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector,
    Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector)
```